# Multiple VU in Jmeter-Only one user able to insert data

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

**Test Plan:-**

```
-User logs in.     
-Enter details in a form and save it(Which is stored in DB).  
-Logs out.
```

When ran with 2 Virtual Users :-

```
-Number Of Threads(users) = 2  
-Ramp Up Period = 1
-Loop Count = 1
```

Only 1 user is able to successfully store the details in DB.
2nd Thread/user give some URLs in response instead of `JSON` Data.
When one thread is used and the script is run many times, it is successfully storing data in DB.

**Elements used in the Test Plan:-**

```
-HTTP Cookie Manager

-View Result Tree
```

Am I missing some elements ?

What mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are replaying the recorded plan for 1 user.

Most probably your issue is due to not variabilizing (Regexp Post-Processor or CSS/Jquery Post Processor to extract and variable to inject) some dynamic data that is needed for the additionnal users.

So when you put 1, it works because IDs correspond to recorded user, but when you put more, at some step you have the second users using the IDs of the first one.

Google "correlation with jmeter" to understand and fix your issue.

Comment: So, Regexp Post-Processor will extract dynamic data or some more elements are needed ?

Answer (score 0):

In case you have the correct script then check the business of your application. As I have experienced some applications don't allow many users submit the form at the same time. It will lock the form for the first user and the second user cannot submit, the second user will receive the response data with messages like "This form is being used by another user..." or "The data on this form is out of date, please refresh...". In that case, I use a Logic Controller, called "Critical Section Controller". It will handle the users to make sure the transaction will be executed by only one user at a time.